# Oracle - Fill up missing characters

Tags: regex, oracle

I have a column which must contain 7 characters. Some of them have less, for instance only 5 or 6 or even less. I have to fill up all missing characters with hashes #. Example:

INPUT:

```
MY_COLUMN
D3T4F2ET
D3T4F2E
D3T4F2
```

OUTPUT:

```
MY_COLUMN
D3T4F2ET
D3T4F2E#
D3T4F2##
```

I tried `regexp_replace(MY_COLUMN, '\s+','#')` but that didn't work. How to archive this?

Comment: Use `rpad(my_column, 7, '#')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need rpad

```
select rpad('ABCD',7, '#') from dual;
```